# Add an image at the mouse's position when clicking with the middle button

Tags: javascript

The problem I have is that the image is placed whether I press the middle or the right button, and it is not positioned at the cursor's location but is offset.

```js
let img = document.createElement("img");

let flag = true;

img.src = "resources/mundo.gif";
img.id = "image";

img.style.position = "relative";
img.style.width = "80px";

let extra = document.createElement("img");
extra.id = "extra";
extra.style.width = "80px";
extra.style.position = "relative";

document.body.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(extra);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    let i = document.querySelector("#image");
    setXY(e, i);
});

document.addEventListener("auxclick", function (e) {
    let ext = document.querySelector("#extra");

    ext.src = "resources/" + ((flag) ? "luna" : "sol") + ".gif"
    setXY(e, ext);

    flag = !flag;
});

function setXY(event, element) {
    const x = event.clientX - element.width / 2;
    const y = event.clientY - element.height / 2;

    element.style.left = x + "px";
    element.style.top = y + "px";
}
```

I want that when clicking with the middle mouse button, an image is placed at the current cursor position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the extra image to account for margin and change the position to absolute, you should get the desired effect. I added these changes to the snippet below (along with example images to see the result).

```js
let img = document.createElement("img");

let flag = true;

img.src = "https://picsum.photos/175";
img.id = "image";

img.style.position = "relative";
img.style.width = "80px";

let extra = document.createElement("img");
extra.id = "extra";
extra.style.width = "80px";
extra.style.margin = "9px";
extra.style.position = "absolute";

document.body.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(extra);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    let i = document.querySelector("#image");
    setXY(e, i);
});

document.addEventListener("auxclick", function (e) {
    let ext = document.querySelector("#extra");

    ext.src = "https://picsum.photos/175"
    setXY(e, ext);

    flag = !flag;
});

function setXY(event, element) {
    const x = event.clientX - element.width / 2;
    const y = event.clientY - element.height / 2;

    element.style.left = x + "px";
    element.style.top = y + "px";
}
```

Comment: Thx, it works perfectly